# how to use ffmpegs's afir in ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

My goal is to slow down a file and add reverberation using python

here's my code:

```
import ffmpeg

audio = ffmpeg.input(r'test_files\Gorillaz - Rhinestone Eyes.mp3').audio
audio = audio.filter('rubberband', tempo=0.8, pitch=0.8, pitchq='quality')
# audio = audio.filter('afir', )
output = ffmpeg.output(audio, r'final\test.mp3', format='mp3', audio_bitrate=320_000)
ffmpeg.run(output)
```

the problem is that I don't know how to properly use afir filter in ffmpeg-python syntax, I tried doing it by hand in command prompt and succeed, but in python it gives me errors

I tried to find information about my problem on the internet, but failed. And also I tried asking chatgpt about all this, but it didn't help either.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you can always use `subprocess.run()` to execute directly `ffmpeg`

Comment: you can use ffmpeg.compile() or ffmpeg.stream_get_args() to check the command the library is generating, that will help you debug the ffmpeg generated command.